# subquery value outside the scope

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT IFNULL(oea.`name`,op.name) AS "Consultation"
FROM `a` ca 
JOIN `b` oea ON ca.`consultation_id` = oea.id AND oea.status = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN c oeal ON oea.`location_id` = oeal.id
WHERE oea.employee_profile_id IN (
                                  SELECT profile_id
                                  FROM d pp
                                  WHERE pp.status='1'
                                  UNION
                                  SELECT op.id
                                  FROM e op
                                  WHERE op.status
                                 ) AND 
      ca.status = 1
```

I am getting this error

```
Unknown column 'op.name' in 'field list'
```

Is there any possibility to use op.name outside the scope?

Comment: Can you make it a derived table instead?

Comment: @Sico I was not that much familiar with derived table, whether that will help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the subquery in the `WHERE` clause instead of using the `IN` predicate. This way you can select the name from it.

But you *didn't* select the column `name` from in the subquery. You selected only the `profile_id`, you have to select it with the `profile_id`. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(oea.`name`, op.name) AS Consultation
FROM `a` ca 
JOIN `b` oea ON ca.`consultation_id` = oea.id AND oea.status = 1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT profile_id, name
    FROM d pp 
    WHERE pp.status='1' 
    UNION    
    SELECT op.id, name 
    FROM e op 
    WHERE op.status
) AS op ON oea.employee_profile_id = op.profile_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c oeal ON oea.`location_id` = oeal.id
WHERE ca.status = 1;
```

I assumed that the two tables have the `name` column, if one of them didn't have it, you have to use `null` instead.

Comment: there two select queries inside the join statement, our db having more than tens of thousands of data, is there any optimized suggestion to get over those select queries because it will affect the performance.

Comment: @Suganthan If these two tables `d` and `e` have the same structure, if possible try to merge both into one table instead and delete the other. If not, the only thing you can do, is to ensure that [**indexes**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) in the table are setup properly. By making an indexes on `employee_profile_id` and `profile_id`, this should speed up the query.

Comment: ok great, merging is not at all possible, indexes we have to go through, thanks for your time